# NGINX: TCP reverse proxy: bind() failed

Tags: nginx, tcp, proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I am trying to use NGINX to set up a TCP reverse proxy in one of my server instances. NGINX is running on port 443 and I have existing https reverse proxy successfully configured on the same NGINX. I have followed the documentation: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/tcp-udp-load-balancer/

I have added the following block in my *nginx.conf*:

```
stream 
    {
        server {
                listen     9042;
                proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:9042;
        }
    }
```

I am trying to connect to cassandra which is running on port 9042 on the same server:

```
lsof -nPi -sTCP:LISTEN | grep 9042
java       5299 cassandra 1325u  IPv4    50914      0t0  TCP *:9042 (LISTEN)
```

After adding the new server block, I validated my *nginx.conf*:

```
 #nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

But when I try to restart I get the following error:

```
<my host>:/etc/nginx# systemctl start nginx
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
<my host>:/etc/nginx# systemctl status nginx.service
● nginx.service - nginx - high performance web server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2022-03-07 15:28:40 EST; 15s ago
     Docs: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
  Process: 10172 ExecStop=/bin/sh -c /bin/kill -s TERM $(/bin/cat /var/run/nginx.pid) (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 13599 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 1676 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Mar 07 15:28:37 <my host> nginx[13599]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:9042 failed (98: Addr...se)
Mar 07 15:28:38 <my host> nginx[13599]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:9042 failed (98: Addr...se)
Mar 07 15:28:38 <my host> nginx[13599]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:9042 failed (98: Addr...se)
Mar 07 15:28:39 <my host> nginx[13599]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:9042 failed (98: Addr...se)
Mar 07 15:28:39 <my host> nginx[13599]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:9042 failed (98: Addr...se)
Mar 07 15:28:40 <my host> nginx[13599]: nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

Comment: You can't use the same TCP port for two processes unless they are both explicitly bound to specific and different IP addresses. Rethink.

Comment: @user207421, I am not using same port for two process, 9042 is used for cassandra and I want to route to that using nginx